# connect localhost to cloudamqp cloud

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, cloudamqp

im new comer in rabbitmq and i want to connect to cloudamqp instance from localhost that i created just for train and test .
but when i run `php artisan rabbitmq:consume` i get this error:

`ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.(0, 0)`

also i previously installed `vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq` for project

queue.php:

```
    'rabbitmq' => [
        'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
        'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'connection' => PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPLazyConnection::class,

        'hosts' => [
            [
                'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT', 5672),
                'user' => env('RABBITMQ_USER', 'guest'),
                'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD', 'guest'),
                'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST', '/'),
            ],
        ],
        'options' => [
            'ssl_options' => [
                'cafile' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE', null),
                'local_cert' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_LOCALCERT', null),
                'local_key' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_LOCALKEY', null),
                'verify_peer' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', true),
                'passphrase' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
            ],
            'queue' => [
                'job' => VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\Jobs\RabbitMQJob::class,
                // 'job' => App\Jobs\CustomHandleJob::class,
            ],
        ],
        /*
        * Set to "horizon" if you wish to use Laravel Horizon.
        */
        'worker' => env('RABBITMQ_WORKER', 'default'),

    ],
```

.env file (credential from instance detail in cloudamqp website):

```
RABBITMQ_HOST=snake-01.rmq2.cloudamqp.com
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_USER=semvcmrb
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=tjsOdrJN5V7hrapL5k3gEM8hpdYin9J
RABBITMQ_VHOST=semvcmrb
```